# kotlin multiplatform coverage?

Tags: testing, kotlin, code-coverage, multiplatform

Is there any tool to measure test coverage in the common portion of a Kotlin multiplatform project?  I'm investigating migrating a Kotlin project to multiplatform.  I'm a TDD developer and the code has 98% coverage.  A good 95% can move to common.  Am I looking at abandoning coverage metrics?

Comment: I just opened a feature request for this on IDEA's bugtracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-241030

Answer (score 8):

I have also a multiplatform kotlin project that uses jacoco for test coverage.

just follow this [guide](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/jacoco_plugin.html)

but there's a need for a little configuration in case you are using gradle kotlin dsl:

```kotlin
plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform") version "1.3.72"
    id("java-library")
    jacoco
}

jacoco {
    toolVersion = "0.8.6"
}

tasks.jacocoTestReport {
    val coverageSourceDirs = arrayOf(
            "src/commonMain",
            "src/jvmMain"
    )

    val classFiles = File("${buildDir}/classes/kotlin/jvm/")
            .walkBottomUp()
            .toSet()

    classDirectories.setFrom(classFiles)
    sourceDirectories.setFrom(files(coverageSourceDirs))

    executionData
            .setFrom(files("${buildDir}/jacoco/jvmTest.exec"))

    reports {
        xml.isEnabled = true
        html.isEnabled = true
    }
}
```

running the command below will generate reports on your `build/reports/test/jacoco`

```
gradle clean build jacocoTestReport
```

Comment: @nwillc do not hesitate to mark an answer as correct if it helped you!

Answer (score 0):

try this: https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx-kover (Gradle plugin for Kotlin code coverage agents: IntelliJ and JaCoCo.)